# Present loading bar while hhtp post request is being handled

Tags: angular, loading, ionic4

Hi i have the following method running in my Ionic 4 
register.page.ts file

```
 register(form) {
this.authService.register(form.value).subscribe(
  result => { // your result from observer.next() in auth.service
    // success
    this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
  },
  error => { // your error from observer.error() in auth.servi
    // no success
    alert('Error detected.');
  }
);
}
```

And the following in my 
authService.ts file

```
register(postData: User): Observable<any> {
return new Observable(observer => {
  this.http.post(`https://fb47b1a2.ngrok.io/register`, postData)
    .pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        return throwError(error); // if you catch any errors, pass them (rethrow) to the error block
      })
     )
     .subscribe(
       result => {
         observer.next(result); // if you receive a result, pass to register function in register.page.ts
         observer.complete(); // close the observable
       },
       error => {
         observer.error(error); // if you receive an error, pass error to register function
         observer.complete(); // close the observable
        }
      );
    });
}
```

These methods work perfectly but i would like to have a loading bar that appears while the HTTP request is happening and then disappear once the HTTP has succeeded or when an error is returned. I have never worked with ionic and have no idea where to put the loading bar component and how to structure it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Ionic 4` so I suppose you'll be using the `ionic way of doing things`, then using the `LoadingController`-service.
You first need to write two methods for logic of showing or hiding the loader, such as:

```
constructor() {
   ...
   private loaderController: LoadingController,
   ...
}

// To show the loader
async showLoader() {
   // You can put here some custom config, but don't add a duration, 
   // otherwise the loader will close prematurely 
   const loader = await this.loaderController.create({});
   await loader.present();
}

// To hide the loader
async hideLoader() {
   await this.loaderController.dismiss();
}
...
```

and then before calling your observable, just call `this.showLoader()` and after that, in the `subscribe` bloc, `this.hideLoader()`:

```
register(form) {
   this.showLoader(); <---- Show here, before the observable
   this.authService.register(form.value).subscribe(
      result => { // your result from observer.next() in auth.service
         // success
         this.hideLoader(); <---- Hide here, in the subscribe logic
         this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
      },
      error => { // your error from observer.error() in auth.servi
         // no success
         this.hideLoader(); <---- Hide here also, in the error-subscribe logic
         alert('Error detected.');
      }
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one from angular material:

https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview

Also if you do not need a loading bar you can go to this page and grab the HTML and CSS for some spinners.

https://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

You need to add it as a component in your main html.

Also this video might be helpful for you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR-Cj1dGgkM

The point in the video:

1.Make the spinner component
         2. Add it to your component html (where you trigger the http request) and add a ngIf directive with a variable initialized as
       false.
3. When you trigger the http request change the ngIf to true so you can see it
         4. When you get the response change the ngIf of the component to false

Here is a quick snippet:

In your ts:

```
loader = false;

     register(form) {
this.loader = true;
    this.authService.register(form.value).subscribe(
      result => { // your result from observer.next() in auth.service
        // success
this.loader = false;
        this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
      },
      error => { // your error from observer.error() in auth.servi
        // no success
        alert('Error detected.');
      }
    );
    }
```

In your html

```
<loader *ngIf="loader"></loader>
```